# Replace \\n with \n in a string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

```
var string = "I have a a string \\nThis is a new line\\nThis is another";
```

what I want is

```
var string = "I have a a string \nThis is a new line\nThis is another";
```

I have used

```
string.Replace("\\","\");
Newline in constant
```

But get the error message "Newline in constant"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you really want to replace is a backslash followed by the letter n with the newline character

```
string.Replace("\\n","\n");
```

The reason `Replace("\\","\")` gives that compilation error is because the backslash is escaping the double quote so the string continues on to the end of the line which is not allowed unless it's a verbatim string (starts with an @).

Answer (score 18):

**Newline in constant** error is caused by the fact that `"\"` is an invalid string literal in C#. You must have meant `"\\"` (to denote one literal `\` symbol).

The `"\\n"` is a string containing 1 literal `\` symbol followed with a literal `n` letter. You need to get `"\n"`, a newline character. There is no `\` here, it is an *escape sequence*. So, replacing `\\` with `\` can't work in principle here.

**If you want to just replace all `\` followed with `n` with a newline, you can just use `.Replace(@"\n", "\n")`**, where `@"\n"` is a **verbatim string literal** that finds a literal `\` + `n`, and replaces with an escape sequence `\n` denoting a newline (LF) symbol.

Also, you may want to use [`Regex.Unescape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.90).aspx) **to convert all escape entities into their literal representations**:

```
var s = "I have a a string \\nThis is a new line\\nThis is another";
Console.Write(Regex.Unescape(s));
```

Result of the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/lXSRNw):

```
I have a a string 
This is a new line
This is another
```

Comment: No, this is just a bad answer.  The problem here is the OP not understanding the intricacies of string literals.  The solution is to explain them as [juharr did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37592780/20938), not to offer too-clever hacks.

Comment: @AlanMoore: You might have missed my explanation in the beginning of the answer. All is explained. Also, this will convert `\\r` (literal ``\`` + `r`) to `\r` (CR symbol), juharr will have to use chained `Replace` methods. A lot depends on the input string itself, its source, what it may contain.

Comment: You didn't explain what was wrong with the replacement string, which is what the error message is referring to.

Comment: That's better, but I still can't endorse recommending `Regex.Unescape()` for this purpose.  Especially to beginning programmers.

Comment: I have been using `Regex.Unescape` for this purpose in my app for more than 5 years, and it works wonders. Just document it correctly and use wisely.

Comment: It works, but only with sequences like `\\t` and `\\n` that boil down to actual characters. `\\s`, for example, throws an exception.  I also tried `\\b`, half expecting it to delete the previous character, but it just became nothing.